# Ajax PHP Redirect to a url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to redirect inside a php file that is called using ajax. Inside the file I write the redirection. But the redirect code is not working.

This is the code for the ajax file:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'admin/includes/front_controller.php';

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $job_id = intval($_POST['id']);
    $job_id = 30;
    $jobdetail = $db->getTableWhere("jobs", "jbid", $job_id);
    $count = count($jobdetail);
    if ($count <= 0) {
        header("Location: jobs.php");
        exit();
    }
} else {
    echo "There is an error processing your request";
}
?>
```

This is the ajax call I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".job-btn").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        //alert(id);
        var url = "<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>" + "jobdetail.php";
        var info = 'id=' + id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: info,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                //alert(data.responseText);
                //alert("Error occured in showing details");
            }
        })

    });
</script>
```

Comment: you can't redirect from a ajaxed page

Comment: Your ajax response should include instructions for your callback to redirect, ie the URL should be in the JSON

Comment: Redirection can never happen inside an AJAX. You will have to write redirect code in `success: function(data) {....`

Answer (score 1):

Redirect using js in the success function

```
success: function (data) {
   alert(data);
   window.location ="jobs.php";
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
header("Location: jobs.php");
```

inside php code, return the url in `response` to the ajax. And use `window.location` in `success` like:

```
 success: function (response) {
     window.location = response;
 }
```